# Split string and then show all items without the last

Tags: javascript

I have (for example) string like `let abc = 'Jonny_Name'`, so if i want to check, this is name or not I check:

```
let isName = abc.split('_')[1];  
 isName === 'Name' ? `your name is ${abc.split('_')[0]}` : 'not name';
```

But I have this situation, when I have string like `let cba = 'Jonny_Great_Dude_Name'`
in this case I check for Name in this way:

```
let isName = cba.split('_').pop(-1);  
 isName === 'Name' ? `your name is ${cba.splitOnLast('_')[0]}` : 'not name'
```

This works fine, but I didn't find any information about `splitOnLast` method. Is this method has some problems with compatible in browsers? Can I make some alternative for this. I want to take all elements without last..

UPD. in console it works fine, but in project I have error message like `item.splitOnLast is not a function`[image]

UPD. like in in first example `Jonny_Name` is became `'Jonny'`, in expect `Jonny_Great_Dude_Name` will be `Jonny_Great_Dude`

Comment: There's no such function as `.splitOnLast` in `Array.prototype`.

Comment: You are right, I find this method in devtools hints..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const abc = 'Jonny_Great_Dude_Name';
const splitted = abc.split(/_/);
const [other, name] = [splitted.pop(), splitted.join('_')];
console.log({name:name, isName: other == 'Name'});
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array.pop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) has no argument - you can use this to get the last element form the split operation

```
let isName = cba.split('_').pop();
```

Or you reverse the new array an take the "first" element:

```
let isName = cba.split('_').reverse()[0]
```

[String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) takes a second argument for the max length of the returned array. This should help you:

```
cba.split('_', cba.split('_').length - 1)
```

or to get it as a string

```
cba.split('_', cba.split('_').length - 1).join("_")
```

Running Example

```js
const cba = 'Jonny_Great_Dude_Name';
const isName = cba.split('_').pop()
const rest = cba.split('_', cba.split('_').length - 1).join("_")
console.log({isName, rest})
```

Comment: Thx for your comment! isName is works fine, I have problem in ``your name is ${cba.splitOnLast('_')[0]}`` where I need to take all string without splited last one :(

Comment: my fault, we need the length of the array from split - 1